# LWJGL 3 Shaders version 150 and above rendering nothing

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, opengl-3

I'm using LWJGL 3 on OSX. The shaders work fine when using a version <150 but porting the code to 330 nothing renders.

My shaders are as simple as possible:

*vertex shader:*

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 position;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

*fragment shader:*

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 outColour;

void main(void) {
  outColour = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I create a simple triangle like this (Scala):

```
val vertices = Array(
   0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
)
val vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length)
vertexBuffer.put(vertices)
vertexBuffer.flip()

val buffer = GL15.glGenBuffers()
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

and I draw it like this:

```
GL20.glUseProgram(shader)
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shader, 0, "position")
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9)

GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
GL20.glUseProgram(0)
```

The shaders compile fine and the program runs but I just get a blank screen! Is there anything obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: Where's your VAO?  Those are required in a Core contexts.

Comment: @j-p: There are no indices involved when drawing with glDrawArrays. Only the glDrawElements family uses indices.

Comment: why the down vote? Please explain so I can improve the question

Comment: @genpfault: Thanks, I didn't realise I needed a VAO. I thought they were something you used instead of VBO's. It's working now. If you want to leave that comment as an answer I'll tick it as the accepted answer

Comment: @OliWinks: You should have posted a [mcve] so we didn't have to guess if you had VAOs or not.

Comment: ok thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: @BDL: thx, I learned something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vertex Array Objects (VAOs)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) are required for rendering in a Core context.  In Compatibility contexts they're optional.

However, you can just generate one at startup and leave it bound if you're feeling lazy :)